# Adding a Checkbox column to a ListView in VB6

Tags: listview, checkbox, vb6

In my version of VB6 the ListView control does not have the `Checkboxes` property, does it have to be added with a special project reference?, or how should I do it, according to [this thread](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?376003-VB6-checkboxes-in-listview) the property does exist on the control,  I've set the `ListView.View` property to `lvwReport`. I've looked at [old forum threads](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/132841.aspx) and the property should be there, what I'm trying to achieve is something similiar to this:

[image: Sample listview with checkboxes]

One method I've seen frequently is to use `lvwMyListView.ListItems(1).Checked = True` to check a specific item, but when I use that all I get is a "Member not found error."

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: In the Properties window, click on About and tell us the version of the control you have. The Microsoft ListView control has a Checkboxes property, and your `lvwMyListView.ListItems(1).Checked = True` statement should be valid

Comment: It says: `ListView ActiveX Control Version 5.0`

Comment: The old 5.0 version didn't have that feature.  This library was supplied along with the 6.0 version to aid in porting old VB5 programs to VB6 until you got around to a rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a VB5 version of the control which does not have the **Checkboxes** property. Write down the properties so you can reset them. You must remove the control(s) from the v5 comctrl32.ocx from the project before you can remove the reference. Open the components window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and uncheck the **Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0** (SP?) and check **Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0 (SP6)**. If you don't have VB service pack 6 installed you should find it and install it first. The versio 6 control has the checkboxes property. There are other controls in the DLL, for instance the **Treeview**, **ProgressBar**, **Slider**, and **ImageList** so if you are using any of these controls, they will be replaced also.

Note: You can have references to both the v5 and v6 versions in use at the same time so you don't have to immediately remove the v5 reference. I wouldn't do it, but if you don't care, and have other v5 controls in your project you could leave it with both references.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Checkboxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443527%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) property.

Comment: I've tried using that, but as mentioned, I get a `Method or data member not found` message.